# Contextual ActionBar?

Tags: android, android-actionbar

In GMail after checking an email (checkbox on the left) ActionBar changes to something like

```
    ------------------------------------ 
    [ v | N selected]

    (ListFragment)

    [ new actions for selected items ]
    ------------------------------------
```

How do I do that in my app? Is there something in ActionBar API I am missing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you are looking for is the [Contextual Action Bar](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/menus.html#CAB).

Comment: exactly what I'm looking for! nice and clean :)

Answer (score 3):

You are probably looking for the Contextual Action Bar: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/menus.html#CAB